# How do I find if the subset (which is the set of all vectors with real nonnegative components) is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I straight-up have no clue how the heck I'm supposed to start of complete this proof. In need to prove or disprove that the subset (the set of all vectors with real nonnegative components) is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$?

My thinking is that the vector would be something like:

$(w, x, y, z)^T$| $w, x, y, z$ are all positive elements of the real numbers

Any help for this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your "thinking is that the vector would be something like:

(w, x, y, z)^T| w, x, y, z are all elements of the real numbers" is not clear. Don't you want them to be nonnegative? + edit your post to include your question in its body (not only in the title).

Comment: What happens when you think about the corresponding question for the one dimensional vector space $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: A proof that a set is (or isn't) a subspace must start with the definition of subspace. Do you know that definition? Are its conditions satisfied for the set in question?

Comment: This seems to be false to me. E.g., $(1,0,0,0)^T$ is in the subset. But if the subset were a subspace, then $-(1,0,0,0)^T=(-1,0,0,0)^T$ would also be in the subset, which it clearly is not.